# querying a collection object

Tags: c#, linq

i have code to get data from some inbuilt library

```
PwCollection Props = PwSrv.GetItem(row["Name"].ToString()).GetProperties();//.AsQueryable();
                                                    foreach (PwItem Prop in Props)
                                                    {
                                                        Console.WriteLine(Prop.Name);
                                                        Console.WriteLine(Prop.Description);
                                                        Console.WriteLine(Prop.Value);
                                                    }
```

But instead of loop every record i want to query in props and get desired value, these are the properties i having into props collection .

[image]

Please help me on query in to this collection .

Thanks 
Dilip

Comment: Without knowing anything about your library there is no way we can help sort out how to call it to query at the source...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your time , i able to solved it

```
DBValue = lpropertycollection.GetProperties().OfType<PwItem>().Where(t => t.Name == row["Name"] + DBColName).FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();
```